# XPath 1.0 COUNT - Unique values

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I've got this test XML:

```
<test>
    <x a="1">
      <x a="2">
        <x>
          <y>y31</y>
          <y>y32</y>
        </x>
      </x>
    </x>
    <x a="1">
      <x a="2">
        <y>y31</y>
        <y>y32</y>
      </x>
    </x>
    <x a="1">
      <y>y11</y>
      <y>y12</y>
    </x>
    <x>
      <y>y11</y>
      <y>y11</y>
    </x>
</test>
```

How can I query:

1 - All values for y

```
y32, y32, y11, y12
```

2 - Number of values for y

I'm trying to use COUNT but I can't count the number of UNIQUE values `y` has, for example if I run query against sample XML described before I need the result to be `4`.

Comment: I suppose you mean you want to compute the result **4** (but `count()` is giving you 5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you've got to work with is XPath (and not XSLT or something of that nature), then I think this is the best you can do:

All distinct `y` values:

```
//y[not(. = preceding::y)]
```

Number of distinct `y` values:

```
count(//y[not(. = preceding::y)])
```

Comment: That's what I came up with, too.  I don't see how you can do better with the available standard functions.