# Xpath 1.0 get unique values with limited scope

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2, xpath-1.0, schematron

I am wokring with XML and XPATH v1.0, specifically using [libxml2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2)'s Schematron module, that I am quite sure that uses the Xpath module for the assert tests. So in order to simplify the problem, lets just think on xpath expressions.

I have the following xml code:

```
<configuration
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <configuration_A>
        <slot_1>
            <type_a>
                <input_1>TEXT_1</input_1>
            </type_a>
        </slot_1>
    </configuration_A>

    <configuration_B>
        <slot_1>
            <type_a>
                <input_1>TEXT_1</input_1>
            </type_a>
        </slot_1>
        <slot_2>
            <type_a>
                <input_1>TEXT_2</input_1>
            </type_a>
        </slot_2>
        <slot_3>
            <type_a>
                <input_1>TEXT_2</input_1>
            </type_a>
        </slot_3>
        <slot_4>
            <type_a>
                <input_1>TEXT_3</input_1>
            </type_a>
        </slot_4>
        <slot_5>
            <type_b>
                <input_1>TEXT_3</input_1>
            </type_b>
        </slot_5>
    </configuration_B>
</configuration>
```

I am trying count the number of unique type_a/input_1's values **within configuration_B**. What would have been in XPATH 2.0 `count(distinct-values(//configuration_B//type_a/input_1/text())`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549298/xpath-1-0-count-unique-values) and similar answers using `preceding` and so I have adapted it as `//configuration_B//type_a/input_1[not(. = preceding::input_1)]` which should give me unique type_a//input_1

However, `preceding` considers as well configuration_A's input_1. Leading to the following output (those should be unique input_1):

- /configuration/configuration_B/slot_2/type_a/input_1
- /configuration/configuration_B/slot_4/type_a/input_1

In case you don't see it, I am missing  */configuration_B/slot_1/type_a/input_1* and */configuration_B/slot_2/type_a/input_1* should not be there.

I have been breaking my head for quite a long, and I start to think it isn't possible with XPATH 1.0, but I want to give a try with stackoverflow.

Note: In case some one finds it useful, I am using [libxml2 example xpath program](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/#XPath) (slightly modified to provide a verbose output) to test expressions.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I accept Heiko Theißen answer as correct: it does obtain the same output than `distinct-values(//configuration_B//type_a/input_1/text()`.
Although it is not what I was looking for. However, he show me the key for my solution. Therefore I want to share it with the community.

As I am trying to identify if there is duplication in order to trigger an assert, what I was missing is "type_a/input_1" after `preceding` and then apply Heiko Theißen's axi suggested test:

```
//configuration_B//type_a/input_1[(. = preceding::type_a/input_1[../../parent::configuration_B])]
```

What would be left is to count and triggering the assert if not 0.

The previous xpath expression doesn't show all instance a duplicated elements. That can be done adding the equivalent `following` test with an `or` operator:

```
//configuration_B//type_a/input_1[((. = following::type_a/input_1[../../parent::configuration_B]) or (. = preceding::type_a/input_1[../../parent::configuration_B])) ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the `preceding::` axis with a test whether the great-grandparent is `configuration_B`:

```
count(/*/configuration_B/*
  /type_a[not(input_1 = preceding::input_1[../../parent::configuration_B])]
)
```

gives 3.

I assumed that you want to disregard the `slot_5/type_b` completely.

Comment: I just noticed that the expression //configuration_B//type_a/input_1[not(. = preceding::input_1)] is giving  /configuration_B/slot_2/type_a/input_1  which is not unique. But i think your statement about "extending the preceding" is on the right direction.